# Check if atleast of the variables have a value in php

Tags: php, magento

I have two variables in php/magento as in below

```
$currentA = $advert->getA();
$currentB = $advert->getB();
```

I want to make sure that atleast one of these have a value....Basically a validation to make sure atleast one of these have a value. Am I doing it correct?

```
   $currentA = $advert->getA();
   $currentB = $advert->getB();
   if (!($currentA != '' || $currentB !== '')) {
           echo "do something";
   }
```

Comment: Looks good...why not:   if ($currentA === '' && $currentB === '') ?

Comment: I want to make sure if atleast one of the variables do not have a value, then do something

Comment: Do you have a specific problem, is it not working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more complicated than that. Like SQL fields, php variables may also be NULL and generate warning when accessed for data.

So use [empty(var)](https://www.php.net/empty) because that tests for all of the possible empty conditions and doesn't give warnings if the variable has been declared without a value.

```
   if (!(empty($currentA) || empty($currentB))) {
           echo "do something";
   }
```

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float) "
- 0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need the `!` because if either of these have a value, it will return true, and the `!` operator checks if this condition is false, so it will work opposite of when it's supposed to. You should try

```
if ($currentA || $currentB) {
       echo "do something";
}
```