# How do I implement that if a checkbox is clicked then dropdown field doesnot need to have value

Tags: php

This is php question. Please see image below. If user clicks on "Click A", then user do not need to select year/month from dropdown. I am trying to implement that logic in server side validation.

I have two variables of the dropdown that are getting the values correctly.

```
    $expiry_year1 = $advert->getRegoExpiryYear();
    $expiry_month1 = $advert->getRegoExpiryMonth();
```

Unfortunately I do not get any values of whether clicked on "Click A".

But, if `$exprity_year == empty && $expirty_month== empty`, then we know that user have clicked on "Clicked A" which is kinda not accurate but that is how it should be.. Can you help me to implement the case?

```
    $expiry_year1 = $advert->getRegoExpiryYear();
    $expiry_month1 = $advert->getRegoExpiryMonth();
    // don't send the rego expiry
    if (!$expiry_year1 || !$expiry_month1) {
        $regoexpirydate = '';
    } else {
        $regoexpirydate = date("Y-m-t", strtotime((!empty($expiry_year1) ? $expiry_year1 : '') . '-' . (!empty($expiry_month1) ? $expiry_month1 : '')));
    }
```

**if($regoexpirydate is anything but "" or a value then do something..**

How do I say that in php?
[image: Image describing the situation]

Comment: Didn't you [ask a similar if not same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707183/check-if-atleast-of-the-variables-have-a-value-in-php) earlier? Seems to be a step-by-step question & answer.

Comment: Why do you not tested if the checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the checkbox to control the select boxes if they are needed to be processed or not, you can also use jquery to control their states as disabled/or not disabled. When they are disabled they will not be included in the process. Consider this example:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // this is not defined if its not checked
    $checked = isset($_POST['click_a']) ? true : false;
    $month = isset($_POST['select1']) ? $_POST['select1'] : null;
    $year = isset($_POST['select2']) ? $_POST['select2'] : null;
    if($checked) {
        // if its checked and select boxes are empty do not process them
        echo 'checkbox a is checked';
    } else {
        // process them
        echo 'checkbox a is NOT checked';
        echo $month . ' - ' . $year;
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="click_a" id="click_a" /> Click A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Registration Expiry:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="select1" id="select1">
            <option selected disabled>Month</option>
            <option>Jan</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
            <option selected disabled>Year</option>
            <option>3000</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// you set the two select boxes to "disabled" when the checkbox is clicked.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click_a').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#select1, #select2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#select1, #select2').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I know I can do so using jQUery. Actualy that is what has been done. But the process is the one that is 2nd defense (if jquery is disabled etc etc).

Comment: @Himu so if you want just a simple validation on php if the checkbox is indeed checked or not, check my edit